# Angular HTTP does not work on first click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On button click I am invoking a method Getdata(); but the problem is when the page is loaded for the first time, if I click on the button then I get "HTTP error" response. but if I click on the button again then it shows success response.

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-inline inline-Magrin" ng-click="Getdata()">Search</button>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.Getdata = function () {
    if (($scope.NumberOfrecords > $scope.TotalRecords) && ($scope.TotalRecords != 0)) {
        alert("Search record count should not be greater than total records");
        return;
    }
    debugger;
    $http({
        url: '/scrap/Resultdata',
        method: "GET",
        params: {
            Searchbox: $scope.Searchbox,
            Category: $scope.Category,
            NumberOfrecords: $scope.NumberOfrecords
        }
    }).then(
        function successCallback(response) {
            response = $scope.filterRecord(response);
            debugger;
            $scope.data = response.data.ResponseItems;
            $scope.TotalRecords = response.data.TotalResults;
            $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 10
            }, {
                data: $scope.data
            });
        },
        function errorCallback(response) {
            debugger;
            alert("error");
        });
}
```

[image: console image]

Comment: The errors in your console are not for a request to `/scrap/Resultdata`. Look at your network traffic and see what the difference is when the request works and doesn't work. I'm guessing some of your `$scope` variables aren't initialized the first time

Comment: Try `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`

Comment: You are messing up your url somewhere, but not in the inserted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

button type was "submit", it should be "button"

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary form-inline inline-Magrin" ng-click="Getdata()">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are having the submit as type, then you need to add the   tags in the html,

and in form  -------- 
        OnSubmit=GetData()

Please try using type=button instead